# What php download script I can use to save canvas as png to local computer?

Tags: php, html, html2canvas

I would like to be able to download the html2canvas into an image file using php download script only. The page have a sliding bar with shapes for the user to select for the exercise. The webpage with the displayed results needs to be capture and saved into an image file.

Below is the script I used embedded in the html code.

```
function triggerPull() {
    if (document.getElementById('name').value != "") {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('body'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('img/png');
                canvas.src = dataURL;
                document.getElementById('url').value = dataURL;
                document.download.submit();
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please fill in your name first.');
    }
}
```

I tried the script below for the downloader.php file. I only get a blank image file named downloader.php.png  Please Help!

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_POST['name'] .'"');
$encoded = $_POST['img'];
$encoded = str_replace(' ', '+', $encoded);
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
echo $decoded;
?>
```

Comment: So, for clarification, the problem is that you are rendering a PNG image via a PHP script, but it is corrupted? Try saving the image to disk from your browser and see if there is an error in the binary stream. For example, if you have any whitespace before your headers, your header commands would cause a warning.

Comment: I only have a little knowledge of the canvas object, but from what I know the content of the canvas probably isn't loaded until runtime by some javascript and as such may not be available for downloading on the server since the javascript will not be run through the interpreter.

Comment: I tried saving to disk from the web browser but I only get "Save as webpage " option.

Comment: Well that would do it - or sometimes right clicking on the (broken) image will give you a "Save image" option. (You need to use @halfer or whatever, as per the below help string, to draw someone's attention to your comment btw).

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$file = $_POST['url'];
$file = str_replace(' ', '+', $file);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=chart.png');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($file);
```

Comment: I tried the code I get the same result except the file name is named downloader.php.

Comment: Inside the downloaded file is the following code: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in <b>C:\blackboard\docs\downloader.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />

Comment: here's the [link](http://mgdevbbapp.devmary.marygrove.edu/Learning%20Spectrum.htm)

Comment: Tell me You will pass both img or name variable to download.php

Comment: I'm not sure on your question. I believe it is the image. I would like for the user to download load the image of the page when mouse click on the save and download button shown on the page here [webpage](http://mgdevbbapp.devmary.marygrove.edu/Learning%20Spectrum.htm)

Comment: I have changed the above code now replace your old code with new code.

Comment: Now it's downloading into a png image file but when I open the file it says "can't open picture because the file appears to be damage, corrupted or too large.

Comment: Replace url to file like $file = $_POST['file'];

Comment: Hmm, be careful with this code - this allows a user to request any file from disk, and thus represents a serious security problem.

Comment: (Downvoting for the above reason; if you fix this code, ping me and I'll undownvote and upvote).

Comment: allows only images to download 
        $file =$_POST['card'];
 header('Content-type: image/png');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=a.png');
 readfile($file);

Comment: @jdnamera: see what happens if you do `http://server/downloader.php?url=/etc/passwd` on a Linux/Unix-like server. You'll get the server's password file delivered as a (undisplayable) PNG file.

Comment: (You need to use @halfer or whatever name to get someone's attention, by the way - I don't need to do so here as I am commenting on your post.)

Comment: I'm using a windows server.